Selecting from random column in PL/SQL
I'm trying to debug a piece of code that ChatGPT suggested but I'm not sure if its even possible. I get no data found error when running this:
SELECT CASE
    WHEN v_column_no = 1 THEN LASTNAMES1
    WHEN v_column_no = 2 THEN LASTNAMES2
    WHEN v_column_no = 3 THEN LASTNAMES3
    WHEN v_column_no = 4 THEN LASTNAMES4
    WHEN v_column_no = 5 THEN LASTNAMES5
    WHEN v_column_no = 6 THEN LASTNAMES6
    END
INTO v_last_name
FROM EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL
WHERE LASTNAME_ID = TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,5171));

I was expecting to get back one random value from one random column (the table has 5170 rows). But I get an error.
Is there an elegant solution to randomly selecting a column in PL/SQL?

what error did you get, and where/how is v_column_no value set?

Well, "no data found" means your query doesn't find anything that matches the conditions. Without knowing your data, we can't say what's your problem. Maybe your v_column_no  isn't a number between 1 and 6. Maybe the value between 1 and 5171 does not exist as lastname_id in this table. That the table has 5170 rows doesn't mean the first id is 1 and the last one 5170. There might be gaps. You need to show us your data and where you define v_column_no.

"elegant" is a subjective measure, and "random" amongst a choice of 6 isn't very random, but perhaps this will help: https://dbfiddle.uk/h3jjcDJM (nb click the run button more than once )

@AdrianMaxwell this selects random column name, but not the value. OP is expecting quote: "... to get back one random value from one random column" end quote.

@dr yes - but with the correct table, and once you remove the quotations, it would choose a "random" column instead of a column name. Think laterally, not literally.

@AdrianMaxwell With correct table, and once you remove the quotation it would chose to raise an ORA-00904. Literally! https://dbfiddle.uk/J4xwWWoi

@dr lol, not what I had in mind, see https://dbfiddle.uk/cH3aagY4

SQL demands that selected columns are exact - you can not use selection of dynamicaly constructed column list.

Is there an elegant solution to randomly selecting a column in PL/SQL?

1. You can use dynamic sql commands with Execute Immediate:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL 
    ( LASTNAMES1 VarChar2(24), LASTNAMES2 VarChar2(24), LASTNAMES3 VarChar2(24), 
      LASTNAMES4 VarChar2(24), LASTNAMES5 VarChar2(24), LASTNAMES6 VarChar2(24), 
      LASTNAME_ID Number(6)
    );
Insert Into EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL
  Select 'Smith',  'Jones', 'Robertson', 'Jordan',    'Mandel',    'Doe',     1 From Dual Union All 
  Select 'Doe',    'Smith', 'Jones',     'Robertson', 'Jordan',    'Mandel',  2 From Dual Union All 
  Select 'Mandel', 'Doe',   'Smith',     'Jones',     'Robertson', 'Jordan',  3 From Dual;

... code that returns 3 randomly selected columns from 3 random ID rows:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Declare 
    v_column_no    Number(6);
    v_last_name    EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL.LASTNAMES1%TYPE;
    v_last_name_id EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL.LASTNAME_ID%TYPE;
    v_column_name  VarChar2(32);
    v_sql          VarChar2(512);
Begin
    For i In 1..3 Loop
        v_column_no := TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 6 ) );
        v_last_name_id := TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 3 ) );
        --
        Select Case   When v_column_no = 1 Then 'LASTNAMES1'
                      When v_column_no = 2 Then 'LASTNAMES2'
                      When v_column_no = 3 Then 'LASTNAMES3'
                      When v_column_no = 4 Then 'LASTNAMES4'
                      When v_column_no = 5 Then 'LASTNAMES5'
                      When v_column_no = 6 Then 'LASTNAMES6'
                End "RANDOM_COL_NAME"
            INTO  v_column_name
        From  Dual;
        --
        v_sql := 'Select ' || v_column_name || ' From EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL Where LASTNAME_ID = ' || v_last_name_id;
        Execute Immediate v_sql INTO v_last_name; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line( 'Pass No.: ' || i || Chr(10) || 
                              'Random column no:   ' || v_column_no || Chr(10) ||
                              'Random lastname id: ' || v_last_name_id || Chr(10) ||
                              'SQL Statement:      ' || v_sql || Chr(10) ||
                              'Selected lastname:  ' || v_last_name || Chr(10) || 
                              '___________________________________________________');
    End Loop;
End;
/

/*      R e s u l t : 
Pass No.: 1
Random column no:   1
Random lastname id: 1
SQL Statement:      Select LASTNAMES1 From EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL Where LASTNAME_ID = 1
Selected lastname:  Smith
___________________________________________________
Pass No.: 2
Random column no:   5
Random lastname id: 2
SQL Statement:      Select LASTNAMES5 From EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL Where LASTNAME_ID = 2
Selected lastname:  Jordan
___________________________________________________
Pass No.: 3
Random column no:   3
Random lastname id: 2
SQL Statement:      Select LASTNAMES3 From EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL Where LASTNAME_ID = 2
Selected lastname:  Jones
___________________________________________________

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.                     */

NOTE:
Instead of Case When selection From Dual you can select the column name from all_tab_columns table, but check the COLUMN_IDs - they are from 1 to n in order of definition in Create Table command. That is why I created ID column last in Sample Data - so lastnames 1 to 6 are column_id 1 to 6 in all_tab_columns.
Select COLUMN_NAME INTO  v_column_name
From   all_tab_columns 
Where  TABLE_NAME = 'EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL' And
       COLUMN_ID = v_column_no;

2. Using SYS_REFCURSOR
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Declare 
    c   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_column_no    Number(6);
    v_column_name  VarChar(32);
    v_last_name_id EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL.LASTNAME_ID%TYPE;
    v_last_name    EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL.LASTNAMES1%TYPE;
    v_sql          VarChar2(512);
Begin
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
        v_column_no := TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 6 ) );
        v_last_name_id := TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, 3 ) );
        --
        Select COLUMN_NAME Into v_column_name 
        From   all_tab_columns 
        Where  TABLE_NAME = 'EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL' And 
               COLUMN_ID = v_column_no;
        --
        v_sql := 'Select ' || v_column_name || ' as rand_lastname From   EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL Where  LASTNAME_ID = ' || v_last_name_id;
        OPEN c FOR v_sql;
        FETCH c INTO v_last_name;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line( 'Pass No.: ' || i || Chr(10) || 
                                  'Random column no:   ' || v_column_no || Chr(10) ||
                                  'Random lastname id: ' || v_last_name_id || Chr(10) ||
                                  'Selected lastname:  ' || v_last_name || Chr(10) || 
                                  '___________________________________________________');
        CLOSE c;
    END LOOP;
End;
/

/*    R e s u l t : 
Pass No.: 1
Random column no:   2
Random lastname id: 1
Selected lastname:  Jones
___________________________________________________
Pass No.: 2
Random column no:   4
Random lastname id: 1
Selected lastname:  Jordan
___________________________________________________
Pass No.: 3
Random column no:   5
Random lastname id: 1
Selected lastname:  Mandel
___________________________________________________

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.           */


Your problem is a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. That may be because your LASTNAME_ID are not in the range 1 .. 5170 so when you generate a random number in that range it does not match with the LASTNAME_ID value of any rows. If you only want a single random row then you can ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE and then select the first (random) row:
DECLARE
  v_column_no PLS_INTEGER := TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 7));
  v_last_name VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN v_column_no = 1 THEN LASTNAMES1
         WHEN v_column_no = 2 THEN LASTNAMES2
         WHEN v_column_no = 3 THEN LASTNAMES3
         WHEN v_column_no = 4 THEN LASTNAMES4
         WHEN v_column_no = 5 THEN LASTNAMES5
         WHEN v_column_no = 6 THEN LASTNAMES6
         END
  INTO   v_last_name
  FROM   EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_last_name);
END;
/

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE external_last_names_all (lastname_id, lastnames1, lastnames2, lastnames3, lastnames4, lastnames5, lastnames6) AS
SELECT LEVEL * 2, 'AAAA' || LEVEL, 'BBBB' || LEVEL, 'CCCC' || LEVEL, 'DDDD' || LEVEL, 'EEEE' || LEVEL, 'FFFF' || LEVEL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5170;

May, randomly, output:
CCCC2754


If you don't want to use PL/SQL then the query could be:
SELECT CASE TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 7))
       WHEN 1 THEN LASTNAMES1
       WHEN 2 THEN LASTNAMES2
       WHEN 3 THEN LASTNAMES3
       WHEN 4 THEN LASTNAMES4
       WHEN 5 THEN LASTNAMES5
       WHEN 6 THEN LASTNAMES6
       END AS lastname
FROM   EXTERNAL_LAST_NAMES_ALL
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

Which may, randomly, output:



LASTNAME




DDDD3472



fiddle
